# How to rename domain and git repository in Cloudbees?

Tags: cloudbees

My project has been renamed, is it possible to rename the Cloudbees domain and also all GIT repositories?

By domain I mean this part: https://forge.cloudbees.com/a/<domain>/repositories

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't change your domain name, but you can create a new account with your new domain.

If you have any subscriptions or resources on your current account that you'd like to migrate to your new one, you can also just file a support ticket and ask them to help you migrate them.